# How to set the shared drives in Docker for Windows?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

How to set the shared drives in Docker for Windows? I am using the latest version 18. Stable and Edge. My settings screen is shown below. It's missing some options like Shared Drives, Advanced and Network, which are shown in the second image. Why am I missing these options?

**My settings:**
[image]

Screen from a website:
[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seems you are Running Docker for Windows using "Windows Containers". If you switch to "Linux containers" you'll see "Shared Drives" option. [Take a look this video](https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cFjIljq6db).

[According Docker documentation:](https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#volumes) shared drives for Windows containers is not implemented.

> Volume mounting requires shared drives for Linux containers (not for
> Windows containers).

**Update:**
Since 2018, Docker for Desktop is using a **new UI**. I recorded a new video showing [how to solve this problem](http://somup.com/crf6olb9c2).

**Update:**
If you are using **WSL2** you will be experiencing same problem. [Take a look this video](http://somup.com/crf6oTb9cP).

Comment: Is this still true in 2020?  I want to containerize some windows console apps, and need to be able to access their logs after the containers are done.

Comment: Hi @DanielWilliams, You are able to create a volume on a Windows container. I hope this helps you:
https://blog.sixeyed.com/docker-volumes-on-windows-the-case-of-the-g-drive/
https://www.assistanz.com/creating-container-volumes-in-windows-2016/

Answer (score 9):

In new UIs they are placed under resources

[image]

Comment: For me this screen just allows me to add a list of folder paths, and it won't allow me to add any network shares

Comment: @e03050 I installed docker, but I don't see File Sharing option though I have Hyper-V feature is enabled. Any suggestion how to fix this?

Answer (score 9):

Ended up here, because the "Shared drives" was missing on my docker settings. If you are missing it too, but docker is set for linux container then it is because WSL 2.

Because if you are using Docker on WSL 2, there is no such option, but you can directly attach volumes from filesystem with `docker run -v c:\...\your-folder:/mount ...` without specifying it in docker settings.

Comment: @diman82 this only works, if you have WSL 2 set up, not in other case. Check other answers too

Comment: @diman82 Right, and when you try to set up volume as I mentioned, what is happening ?

Comment: I get an empty folder in container. Can you please post you mount command (as an example)?

Comment: docker run --publish 8080:8080 --env PUBLIC_KEY=FOO --env DB_PASSWORD=BAR --env DB_SERVER=localhost --env DB_NAME=liferay --env DB_USER=liferay -v C:\projects\liferay\volume:/mnt/osgi its1-liferay:1.0 - I see only difference in slashes vs. backslashes